# Automate PuTTY via batch and execute the errlog command

Tags: putty, plink

I am brand new to PuTTY.  I am trying to automate retrieving data from the `errlog` command via batch.  FWIW, I installed “Simon Tatham Putty .76” on Windows 10 and am using the Windows command line.   Here’s where I’m at so far:

```
putty.exe -ssh user@SERVER -pw TheActualPassword
```

^ This brings up the terminal with the user successfully logged in:

```
Using username "user".
Last unsuccessful login: Tue Dec 26 11:26:13 CST 2023 on ssh from 111.15.171.117
Last login: Mon Mar 11 23:23:59 CDT 2024 on ssh from 111.15.171.117
$
```

I type in **errlog**, press Enter, get:

```
IDENTIFIER TIMESTAMP  T C RESOURCE_NAME  DESCRIPTION
60D73419   0305122424 I S vnicserver0    VNIC Client Login
<and several more lines>
$
```

I reviewed the documentation and discovered command line options, such as -m, which tells PuTTY to “read a remote command or script from a file”.  I created a test file named ErrlogCommands.txt, and there is one line:

```
errlog
```

Now, I try:

```
putty.exe -ssh user@SERVER -pw TheActualPassword -m ErrlogCommands.txt
```

The terminal literally flashes on and then off.  It took me several tries, but I was able to capture it before it disappeared:

```
Using username “user”
rksh: errlog:  not found.
```

I also tried:

```
putty.exe -ssh user@SERVER -pw TheActualPassword -m ErrlogCommands.txt > a.txt
```

but this simply created an empty file named a.txt.

PLINK looked interesting, so I tried

```
PLINK.exe -ssh user@SERVER -pw TheActualPassword -m ErrlogCommands.txt -batch
```

No terminal popped up, but the command line had this response:

```
rksh: errlog:  not found.
```

What am I missing?  Does the ErrlogCommands.txt file require control characters of some sort?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48445395/850848

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a `PATH` issue, where `errlog` is not on your `PATH` when you try to run the command through putty/plink. This is usually because they start a [non-interactive session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313389/script-via-plink-in-bat-behaves-differently) when given commands to run, which can behave differently.

You can try manually running `which errlog` to find the full path to the executable, then replace the command in your script with the full `/path/to/errlog`:

Comment: Unfortunately, both `which` and `which errlog` both resulted in:
`rksh: which:  not found.`
Following an idea on a few posts into your "non-interactive" link, I tried using the following line in my ErrlogCommands.txt file:
`/sbin/errlog`
but I get the following returned:
`rksh: /sbin/errlog: 0403-019 The operation is not allowed in a restricted shell.`

Comment: @dan400man ah, `rksh` is a restricted shell, which I'm less familiar with. Depending on the OS+settings, you may have very few normal commands available. You could try adding `-t` to plink like `plink.exe -ssh user@server -pw password -t errlog`

Comment: I discovered that one of my colleagues has "enough to be dangerous" experience with AIX and PuTTY.  He agreed that the restricted shell was locking out my script.  He found that `errlog` is actually an alias of the command `ioscli` and, so, the solution was to use: `ioscli errlog` in my ErrlogCommands.txt file.  Now works like a charm!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!